# A series representation

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find the end of a series representation of the product
$$
\prod_{\substack{i=1...\infty\\\ j=0...i\\\ k=0...j}}\frac{1}{1-x^{i-j}y^{j-k}z^{k}}?
$$

For example for product
$$
\prod_{\substack{i=1...\infty\\\ j=0...i}}\frac{1}{1-x^{i-j}y^j}
$$ 
the ends of series is
$$
...+7x^5 + 12x^4y + 16x^3y^2 + 16x^2y^3 + 12xy^4 + 7y^5 + 5x^4 +\\\ +7x^3y + 9x^2y^2 + 7xy^3 + 5y^4 + 3x^3 + 4x^2y + 4xy^2+\\\ + 3y^3 + 2x^2 + 2xy + 2y^2 + x + y + 1
$$

Comment: I think there's an error in your indexing. Consider the example product. Because the power of y always starts with j=1, there should be no pure x power in the series.  (I posted this by accident as an answer.  I'm reposting it here in case someone with the appropriate MO clout can delete its appearance as an answer.  I couldn't figure out how to delete the answer myself.)

Comment: What technique to find the end of a series representation of the product from example?

Comment: @Alexander, I don't understand your question.  My point is, if you let $y=0$, then every term in your product is 1, so its series cannot end $\cdots + 3x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1$.

Comment: If y=0 this product
$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1-x^n}
$$
 will be generating function of number of partitions of $n$
$$
1+x+2x^2+3x^3+5x^4+7x^5...
$$
(https://oeis.org/A000041). 

Comment: @Alexander: that would be for $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \prod_{j={\bf 0}}^i \dfrac{1}{1-x^{i-j} y^j}$, not $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \prod_{j={\bf 1}}^i \dfrac{1}{1-x^{i-j} y^j}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example should be 
$$ \prod_{i=1}^\infty \prod_{j=1}^i \dfrac{1}{1-x^{i-j} y^j} = 1+y+2{y}^{2}+xy+3{y}^{3}+2x{y}^{2}+{x}^{2}y+{x}^{3}y+3{x}^{2}{
y}^{2}+4x{y}^{3}+5{y}^{4} + \ldots$$
The triple product is
$$ \eqalign{\prod _{i=1}^{\infty } & \prod _{j=1}^{i}  \prod _{k=1}^{j}
 \dfrac{1}{ 1-{x}^{i-j}{y}^{j-k}{z}^{k}} \cr & =1+
z+2{z}^{2}+xz+yz+3{z}^{3}+2x{z}^{2}+2y{z}^{2}+{x}^{2}z+xyz+{y}
^{2}z\cr&+{x}^{3}z+3{x}^{2}{z}^{2}+{x}^{2}yz+4x{z}^{3}+x{y}^{2}z+3xy
{z}^{2}+{y}^{3}z+3{y}^{2}{z}^{2}+4y{z}^{3}+5{z}^{4}+\ldots\cr}
$$
EDIT: If you meant the $j$ and $k$ indexing to start from $0$ instead of $1$, 
$$
\eqalign{\prod _{i=1}^{\infty } & \prod _{j=0}^{i}  \prod _{k=0}^{j}
 \dfrac{1}{ 1-{x}^{i-j}{y}^{j-k}{z}^{k}} \cr & =
1+x+y+z+2\,{x}^{2}+2xy+2xz+2{y}^{2}+2yz+2{z}^{2}+3{x}^{3}+
4{x}^{2}y+4{x}^{2}z\cr&+4x{y}^{2}+5xyz+4x{z}^{2}+3{y}^{3}+4{
y}^{2}z+4y{z}^{2}+3{z}^{3}+5{x}^{4}+7{x}^{3}y+7{x}^{3}z+9{
x}^{2}{y}^{2}\cr&+11{x}^{2}yz+9{x}^{2}{z}^{2}+7x{y}^{3}+11x{y}^{2}
z+11xy{z}^{2}+7x{z}^{3}+5{y}^{4}+7{y}^{3}z\cr&+9{y}^{2}{z}^{2}+7
y{z}^{3}+5{z}^{4}+\ldots\cr}$$

Comment: Thank you. How to get this? Or where I can see more members of the series?

Comment: First of all, if you only want terms up to total degree $d$ you only need to take $i=1..d$.  I used Maple's mtaylor command.

Comment: Can you write youre Maple's commands?

Comment:  P4:= product(product(product(1/(1-x^(i-j)*
    y^(j-k)*z^k),k=0..j),j=0..i),i=1..4);

 mtaylor(P4,[x,y,z],5);